# Dart: I made a function async but still can't use await

Tags: flutter, dart

I made a function `async` but still can't use `await` expression. What am I wrong? My code is like this.

```
Future<void> _aFunction() async {
  DocumentReference docRef = Firestore.instance.collection('collection').document(docId);

  docRef.get().then((DocumentSnapshot docSnapShot) {
    if (docSnapShot.exists) {
      String ip = await Connectivity().getWifiIP();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because here is an internal (anonymous) function declaration inside `then`, which is not async. Actually, `await` keyword can be thought as a syntactic sugar over `then`, so it would be convenient to refactor the function like this:

```
Future<void> _aFunction() async {
  final DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection('collection').document(docId).get();
  if (snapshot.exists) {
    String ip = await Connectivity().getWifiIP();
    // Rest of the `ip` variable handling logic function
  }
  // Rest of the function
}
```

Now `await` keyword corresponds to the `_aFunction` itself instead of an anonymous function declared inside `_aFunction`, so it works as expected.

Comment: I think I need to use `await` before getting the document snapshot. Otherwise it caused an error.

Comment: `await` can only be applied to `Future`s, whereas `get` method returns one. Which error do you get?

Comment: It says A value `Future<DocumentSnapshot>` can't be assigned to a variable type of `DocumentSnapshot`.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Side effect of writing a code without an analyzer :) I've edited the question.

Comment: Glad to help :)